# Marketing Cloud - API to create email send definitions(user-initiated sends)

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was able to create Email Send Definitions(User-Initiated Sends) with JSON and REST using the Python FuelSDK, but I am trying to send a call without FuelSDK and can't figure out what REST endpoint to send to.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could also use the NEW transactional triggered send https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm

Comment: I found the answer, the REST End point is "(Your REST Base URL)/automation/v1/automations". Your REST Base URL can be found in Setup > Apps > Installed Packages > (Your API Package). You can refer to @Gortonington 's blog for more on using REST in the Automation Studio https://gortonington.com/creating-a-triggered-automation-in-sfmc-via-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented or undocumented REST API endpoint to accomplish this, you will need to utilize [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_email_send_definition_using_the_web_service_api.htm) to accomplish this.

You would need to target the EmailSendDefinition object using the Create method. Sample envelope below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-9560865" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">             <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>          </wsse:UsernameToken>       </wsse:Security>    </soapenv:Header>    <soapenv:Body>
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="ns1:EmailSendDefinition" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <CustomerKey>Market2Lead_Email_Definition_Key</CustomerKey>
            <Name>Market2Lead_Email_Definition</Name>
            <SendClassification>
               <Client>
                  <ID>75741</ID>
               </Client>
               <ObjectID>4819efef-4527-dd11-8126-001a4be9433a</ObjectID>
               <CustomerKey>3542</CustomerKey>
               <Name>Default Commercial</Name>
               <Description>Default Commercial Send Classification</Description>
               <SenderProfile>
                  <CustomerKey>1973</CustomerKey>
               </SenderProfile>
            </SendClassification>
            <SendDefinitionList>
               <CustomObjectID>1a3e2c14-580e-de11-b30f-001cc494ae9e</CustomObjectID>
               <DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</DataSourceTypeID>
            </SendDefinitionList>
            <Email>
               <ID>794527</ID>
               <Name>Market2Lead</Name>
               <Subject>Market2Lead-Email</Subject>
               <Status>New</Status>
            </Email>
            <IsMultipart>true</IsMultipart>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST transactional Messaging API (POST /messaging/v1/email/definitions) to create send definitions or you can use the SOAP API to create email send definition that uses data extensions to send emails.

REST API reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm

SOAP API Reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_email_send_definition_using_the_web_service_api.htm